# Use of sprite Image in magento 2 pages

Tags: magento2, css, cache

Need a suggestion for sprite image use. I am using single sprite image for website buttons. But I am little bit confused for this. I created a single sprite image for all buttons in website. Is that okay?

OR I need to create multiple sprite images on page base. Like separate image for Cart page buttons and separate image for Checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't do anything special with sprites so you can use them entirely how you want, you can group them up so you have a product page sprite, CMS page sprite, homepage sprite etc. Or you could have one large sprite for the whole site.

It fully depends on the project, for example how many icons/images are there? If there's only 10 for the whole site then a global sprite is probably best, if there are 100+ then it makes sense to split them up.

On a side note, why do you need an image for buttons?

Comment: Hello Ben Crook, actually I created a sprite image with 30+ images. It is loading on all pages. So, I need a suggestion. Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: I find automating it with a task runner such as Gulp/Grunt really helps, it takes the stress of sprites away almost completely.